# How to wrap two text elements around sibling image element

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have three sibling elements image A, title B, copy C. At different widths they should align like this:

1. A and B in a row over C
   [image]
2. B and C in a column to the right of A
   [image]

I can't think of a way to transition from layout #1 to #2 with CSS. Here's the code for #1.

```css
.story {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 0 -7.5px;
}

.story>* {
  padding: 0 7.5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.story .image {
  flex: 0 0 165px;
}

.story h2 {
  flex: 1 0 150px;
}

.story p {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="story">
  <div class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></div>
  <h2>This is where the title goes</h2>
  <p>This is where the copy goes. This is where the copy goes. This is where the copy goes.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the parent element to a fixed height with a padding-left and absolute positioning the image within that padding. Not elegant but it works.